# GTA V Online xbox 360 and one sync

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I have both an xbox one and 360 both with GTA V. I originally started on the 360 and later synced my account to the one. However when I play on the xbox 360 it does not affect my xbox one files and vise versa. Is it possible to get these to sync?

Comment: Have you tried syncing whenever you make changes?

Comment: Yes, it tells me all the character information has already been brought over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you initially copy your character they become 2 separate entities, in the same way your story an achievements are separate across both console.

Comment: So there is no way of syncing?

Comment: Sorry. Only just seen this comment. 
No. It only allows the one copy as far as I am aware.